# Cannot choose suitable keyboard configuration for Canyon CNE-CKEY01-US keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I bought a Canyon CNE-CKEY01-US keyboard and cannot choose the right keyboard configuration in Ubuntu for it. Some keys do not correspond to the notes on buttons if I choose US or GB layout. If I choose US layout then instead of backslash it shows `<`. If I choose GB layout then instead of `@` it shows `"`.
The keyboard looks like this:
[image]
(Source: http://canyon.eu/product/cne-ckey01-us/)

Please advice me how to configure it the best way.